# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a code that does either an interpolation or a curve fitting of a certain number of experimental points stored in a database. Part of this application allows the user to add new points to the data.

This is that part of the code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog = Newtcf;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sqlq As String = "Insert into Points (x-axis,y-axis,weight) Values (@x-axis,@y-axis,@weight)"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlq, connection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@x-axis", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@y-axis", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TextBox2.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@weight", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TextBox3.Text

    connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near '-'.

And the line:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

is highlighted in green. I honestly have no clue what the issue is, or what the "exception" means. And help from our instructors is not readily available. I'd really appreciate some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because special character `'-'`. You shoud delimite column names. Change to:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog = Newtcf;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sqlq As String = "Insert into Points ([x-axis],[y-axis],[weight]) Values (@x,@y,@w)"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlq, connection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@y", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TextBox2.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@w", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TextBox3.Text
    connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Look for details here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have hyphens in your column name the column must be wrapped in square brackets i.e. x-axis becomes [x-axis].

If you run query

```
SELECT x-axis 
FROM BLAH
```

it would actually be trying to subtract column `axis` from column `x`.

I would also avoid using non-alphanumeric characters in your `@` variables unless it's an underscore.

Try this:

```
Dim sqlq As String = "Insert into Points ([x-axis],[y-axis],[weight]) Values (@x_axis,@y_axis,@weight)"
```